# jQuery how to find last enabled child's val in a dependant drop down list

Tags: jquery, ajax

I combined many scripts to get what I want, but didnt suceed. Im glad if you guys can help.

I have 4 drop dependant drop downs. Last 3 drop downs as `disabled` until you select an options from the first one. Then the second gets populated. Not everytime all 4 dropdowns have data. So I want to get the `value` of the last enabled drop down's selected option.

```
<form action="" id="pfilterForm" method="post">
  <select name="make" id="make" class="update">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="13">Range Rover</option>
    <option value="11">Jaguar Performance and Tuning</option>
  </select>
  <select name="series" id="series" class="update">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="81">SLS</option>
    <option value="76">SL-Class</option>
    <option value="32">M-Class</option>
  </select>
  <select name="model" id="model" class="update">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="73">CLK55</option>
    <option value="71">CLK63</option>
  </select>
  <select name="badge" id="badge" class="update" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">----</option>
  </select>
  <button name="data" type="button" onClick="getData()">Click</button>
</form>
```

As you can see `#badge` drop down is disabled at the moment because it doesnt have any data. I have selected `CLK63` with `value` `71`. How do I get that value? Please let me know if I dont make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(".update:not(:disabled) option:selected").last().val()
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuPCM/4/)

Answer (score 2):

`visible` selector is use to see the element which is visible and `last()` helps you to find the last element, you can try:

Edit:

to filter disabled element use `:disable` ant with `:not` it returns elements which are not disabled:

for value:

```
alert($('.update:not(:disabled) option:selected').last().val())
```

and for text:

```
alert($('.update:not(:disabled) option:selected').last().text())
```

[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuPCM/3/)

Comment: His select elements are visible, just disabled. Your jQuery selector will get the disabled select as the last element, which user1889007 does not desire.

Comment: @user1889007 Well his original answer was incorrect, as he assumed your selects were invisible, not disabled....